# How to Customize Source Locations for Manifest File in OfficeJS

Tags: customization, manifest, outlook-addin

I am trying to create a [Manifest](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/add-in-manifests) file for Outlook JS. In the file, there are source locations that are hard-coded into the file. Is there a way to set the domain for all source locations, so that different clients can have their own URL for the add-in's location?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you can really only have one source location - your web server that's "powering" the add-in and serving the source pages.  You can certainly publish your add-in to multiple web servers, but you will have to change the source domains in your manifest for every web server and keep any code changes in sync across all of these different locations.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main parts for any office add-in: website/app (hosted somewhere) manifest (which has hardcoded references to this "somewhere"). For example you have several hosted apps. This may be the same app with slight modification for particular customer (for example branding image or something). Those apps would have different URIs. You are asking how can you customize your second part of the app, manifest, to include those URIs per customization. There are many ways to accomplish this:

- You may have centralized company build location (server) where you may have list of customers and build your manifest per customer in the list. Each customer would get their own manifest file.
- You may do this manually. Leave inside manifest file a placeholder: "replace_me_with_deployment_URI" and instruct your customer to replace this placeholder after yet another app deployment, when they know app's URI.
- You may host those custom apps on your own environment. Deploy customized manifest with your app and when done supply your customer with URL to this manifest, which will be pointed to their custom instance of the app.

The last option would be easiest for your prospective customers to deploy via obtaining just URL of the custom manifest. For your company it would give flexibility to upgrade your app with easy at any time.